# How to track when user kicked Telegram Bot using python-telegram-bot (Bot API 5.1)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

[Telegram introduced Bot API 5.1](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#march-9-2021) with [ChatMemberUpdated](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) and the fields `my_chat_member` and `chat_member` in the Update class.

But how to track when the user stopped the bot now if I'm using ConversationHandler?

Previously, my bot was waiting for commands like **/cancel** or **/stop**.

```py
conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=...,
    states=...,
    fallbacks=[
        # ...
        MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^/(cancel|stop)$'), flow_stop_chat),
        # ...
    ],
    allow_reentry=True,
    name=current_bot_label,
    persistent=True,
)
```

How to do that correctly now using **ChatMemberUpdated**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the update using [ChatMemberHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.chatmemberhandler.html) (new in PTB v13.4) and check `update.my_chat_member.new_chat_member.status` to see if your bot was blocked. However blocking a bot is not quite the same as simply sending a `/cancel` command, so I'd suggest to keep the `MessageHandler` (or better yet, change it to `CommandHandler(['cancel', 'stop'], flow_stop_chat)`)